# Pyenv is not switching to system wide pip when going back to system python

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, python3

I have the following problem...sort to speak..

I've installed pyenv in a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 couple days back and only installed one python 3.9 using it.

```
pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/version)
3.9.12
```

Now I noticed when switching to system python (3.10) it seems

```
python3
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

That the pip used is one referenced in my home folder at .local

```
which pip
/home/internetmosquito/.local/bin/pip
which pip3
/home/internetmosquito/.local/bin/pip3
```

I honestly don't even recall when or how these 2 got there...maybe while installing pipenv? In any case, I wonder why pyenv won't switch to the pip which are living in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages...by the way I actually seem to have 2 directories there, one for python3 and another for python3.10...

```
ls -ltra /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages | grep pip
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 abr 25 16:01 pip-22.0.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   4096 abr 25 16:01 pip
```

So, now if I enable again the python 3.9 with pyenv

```
pyenv global 3.9.12
python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr 25 2022, 16:30:54) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
which pip
/home/internetmosquito/.local/bin/pip
```

By the way, I have another pip in where python 3.9 lives

```
ls -ltra /home/internetmosquito/.pyenv/versions/3.9.12/bin/ | grep pip         
-rwxrwxr-x 1 internetmosquito internetmosquito      264 abr 25 16:31 pip3.9
-rwxrwxr-x 1 internetmosquito internetmosquito      264 abr 25 16:31 pip3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 internetmosquito internetmosquito        6 abr 25 16:31 pip -> pip3.9
```

So basically 2 questions...

1.- Can I remove those pip(s) in my .local folder without compromising the system?

2.- Why pyenv does not enable the pip that is living inside the python 3.9 installed?

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with pyenv per se, but how you are managing your packages.  Do you use *venv*  for example?  If so, then you may have pip3 versions in virtual environments. In that case you'll need to be careful when you *activate* and *deactivate* such environments.

Comment: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv might be a good link to read and absorb.

Comment: @mondotofu nope, I don't, never liked venv and not even now that is part of the standard library. I prefer using either Pipenv or Poetry.